# Writing drivers for DOS. Where to begin?

Tags: driver, dos

I know its possible to write DOS drivers, but I was wondering if there are still books or people out there with that knowledge. I want to run FreeDOS and be able to use my USB keyboard and mouse, and I am guessing I need to write USB drivers.

Where would I even begin?

Comment: You may already be aware of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS#Universal_Serial_Bus).

Comment: Yes I am, the computer I am wanting to run FreeDOS on doesn't seem to emulate "Legacy USB". On my newer computer it does, but I would like to run it on my older one. Thanks though.

Comment: You should begin in 1980-1985, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here: http://www.drdobbs.com/writing-ms-dos-device-drivers/184402277

Also, check out CuteMouse(http://cutemouse.sourceforge.net) for mouse drivers. Maybe this will give you an idea of how they are written.

Comment: Just downloaded the source to CuteMouse, and that's a lot to take in. I don't actually know assembly yet (I can figure some of it out), I just was wanting to know if its reasonably possible to get it done.